# Custom cell in UITableView (iOS 9)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2, ios9

I have simple tableview with custom cell that contains uibutton. After update to iOS 9 GM or 9.1 Beta 1(it doesn't matter) button on cell stopped to response on touch. I have also create IBAction method inside cell class and it's also doesn't work at all

```
cell.username.setAttributedTitle(attrNameString, forState: .Normal)
cell.username.tag = notify.likeObject.likedUserId.integerValue
cell.username.addTarget(self, action: "showProfile:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: Edit title of your question. Current title should be in tags.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found a fix. The issue when I am creating cell from XIB. So I added `self.contentView.userInteractionEnabled = false` to cell class and it's solved the issue